# Convert fraction of a day into a time

Tags: python, time

Given a fractional component of a day, such as `0.12345`, where the number `1` represents a full day, what would be the best way to convert that into a string-formatted time, such as:

```
01:02:03
```

My thinking the simplest approach might be to create two dates and subtract the difference using a `timedelta` settings the number of days to my decimal, but this seems a bit heavy-handed for this.

This gets me close, but not quite...

```
str(datetime.timedelta(days=0.12345)).split('.')[0]
'2:57:46'
```

Comment: For example 0.1 should return 2.4 hours ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya -- correct, I'm using the Excel convention for time.

Comment: The simple logic would be to do 24*0.1 to get 2.4. And if you want to be precise at minute level, you can do 1440*0.1 which will give you 144 minutes. You can convert them to hours and minutes by doing 144/60 and 144%60.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take the number and multiply by 24 to get the hours. The fractional part of the answer can then be multiplied by 60 to get the minutes. Then the fractional part of that answer can now be multiplied by 60 again to get the number of seconds. For example, if you number was 0.582 then 24* 0.582 = 13.968. 13 hrs. Now take fractional part .968*60 = 58.08 so 58 minutes. Now take .08 *60= 4.8 seconds. Your time is 13 hrs 58 minutes and 4.8 seconds.